# Invalid step structure

Tags: circleci

I believe my configuration is valid after reading the [CircleCi workflow documentation](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/) but I am still getting the error below. What is wrong with my configuration?

Here is my workflow configuration:

```
workflows:
  version: 2
  build_assemble_deploy:
    jobs:
      - build
      - assemble:
          requires:
            - build
          filters:
            branches:
              only: master
      - deploy:
          requires:
            - assemble
          filters:
            branches:
              only: master
```

And here is the full error CircleCi gives me:

> Build-agent version 0.1.799-f865b43f (2018-10-11T12:48:06+0000)
>   Configuration errors: 1 error occurred:
>
> - In step 2 definition: Invalid step structure (expected string or
>     map, got config.StepDescription)

Answer (score 1):

The workflow configuration is fine. The issue is in the definition of step 2, in this case the definition of the `assemble` job. The definition is found in the configuration under `job:` > `assemble:`.

In this case the issue was an extra `-` character. This was the configuration:

```
- attach_workspace:
    - at: ~/dir
```

The correct configuration is:

```
- attach_workspace:
    at: ~/dir
```